# Handlebar support for Webstorm

Tags: prettier

Is that plugins support Handlebar templates in Webstorm IDE. I tried some wsettings but not worked prettier. If anyone ahve information about that, it will be perfect for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prettier does not support Handlebars.

> There is no plans to add support for Handlebars outside of Glimmer's
> subset. Prettier's plugin API can be used to create a plugin for it. [Support Handlebars](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/5340#issuecomment-641954294)

Comment: That said, `--parser glimmer` works in cases where Glimmer's subset is enough.